# 100% height for div inside another div with margins

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a `div` inside a `div`. The CSS/HTML is below. I am trying to figure out how to make the inner `div` have true `height: 100%;` with no overflow and what not. No matter what I try the border of the inner div gets cropped because of the outer div's `overflow: hidden`.

For reasons I cannot modify the content or style of either divs. I can, however, wrap the inner div in other divs if needed. This is not done through JavaScript which is why I cannot modify the outer or inner divs.

Also, this has to work in IE8.

The outer div style won't change much -- only the width, height, background-color, and margin.

The inner div could be anything. It could have a bigger border, it could have no border, it could be who knows what.

```css
#outer
{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: yellow;
 margin: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}

#wrapper
{
  height: 100%;
}

#inner
{
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">
   a
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If parent has overflow one way and you want child to have it different, you must specify it on child.

Comment: But I don't want the inner child content to overflow in the outer. The inner div should fill up 100% height and width of the available space within the outer div.

Comment: @AllDani I included the fiddle in the question but here is one on the site directly: https://jsfiddle.net/yetszjr5/.

Comment: I don't see the jsfiddle link in the question

Comment: @AllDani Sorry, I meant I included the code snippet thingy in the question. I thought that is what we use instead of jsfiddle now. My bad.

Comment: Generally, it's best to have both. It's also free ;)

Comment: Try adding a screenshot of what happens and what you would like to happen.

Comment: Not sure how to take a screenshot of what I would like it to do since I can't get it to do what I want. Basically I've got an outer box of some dimension with margins. I'd like to have an inner box that will have arbitrary HTML but it should be 100% height and width of that outer box (inside the margins of course). I hope that makes sense...

Comment: Try using paint (windows) or preview (MacOS)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use css flex property for `#wrapper`

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
#outer
{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: yellow;
 margin: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}

#wrapper /* adding flex */
{
  display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
height: 100%;
}

#inner
{
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">
   a
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

it will work on all latest browser but this won't work on IE8.

Comment: I am unable to modify the style/code for #inner. Is there anyway to get this done by modifying #wrapper?

Comment: is it possible for you to traverse like this `#wrapper #inner {box-sizing: border-box;}`

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0r1y5h89/)

change the `#wrapper` height to only 99% will solve the problem.

The reason why the inner is getting cut off because:

```
#inner {
    height: 100%; //this means it equals to 200px
    border: 1px solid red;  //1px at the top border and 1px at the bottom added to the height of the #inner so now it becomes 202px, which will get cut off by overflow:hidden
}
```

Comment: but i think this won't work if the border width is crossing over 1px. according to the OP the border width may vary.

Comment: Yeah, your are right! But this at least point out why it gets cut off by overflow:hidden since @IMTheNachoMan cannot figure it out